# Comparing a hashed string in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am attempting a small project with a login screen that will hash a password when a user creates login details, and stores it in an XML file. When the user logs in, it hashes the recently entered password, and compares it to the password that is underneath the matching username.

The problem I am facing is that I believe it is somehow adding the username to the password and comparing that. I set breakpoints and confirmed that the hashes are exactly the same. An example of my XML file:

```
<Users>  
   <User>  
     <Username>Tom</Username>
     <Password>1981188637181704932922387266155158141224105130616330512161251851292213221146244100</Password>
   </User>  
</Users>
```

And here is my code for when a login takes place:

`private bool GetUser(string username, string password, string path)
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hPass = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
            password = string.Empty;
            var result = (from item in 
            XDocument.Load("users.xml").Descendants("User")
            where item.Element("Username").Value == username &&
            item.Element("Password").Value == Encoding.Default.GetString(hPass)
            select item).FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }`

If I were to look at the value I'm pulling it reads
`"Tom1981188637181704932922387266155158141224105130616330512161251851292213221146244100"`

Not sure if that is the way is supposed to look or if I have made an error in my code. I feel that is the problem seeing as I have double checked and the comparison should return correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.Value` will look like that as `Value`: *Gets or sets the **concatenated** text contents of this element.*

You should end up with the correct `user` element where `result.Element("Username")` is `Tom`.

The password in your XML looks to be encoded some how, whereas `Encoding.Default.GetString(hPass)` will not return a string in that format...

Comment: I tried doing them separately (user and password) and yes, user returns fine, whereas password does not. And ah, I was told I had to use that on byte arrays as `.ToString()` wouldn't work? Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: Well a byte array -> string will contain unprintable chars an will look nothing like what's in the XML.  Base64 encoding when you save/hash will let you work with strings